# greater than and less than a date gives no records in sequelize but works with heidisql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

It's really weird, I can't debug the issue. I also don't know what's causing the issue.
I have a query like below:

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Op = sequelize.Op
const TODAY_START = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
const NOW = new Date()

    const  data = await AssignedJob.findAll({
        where: {
            created_on: {
                [Op.gt]: TODAY_START,
                [Op.lt]: NOW
            }
        }
    })
```

It generates a query like below.

```
SELECT `id`, `emp_id`, `zone_id`, `job_id`, `status`, `commission`, `rating`,
`created_by`, `updated_by`, `created_on`, `updated_on` 
FROM `assigned_jobs` AS `AssignedJob` 
WHERE (`AssignedJob`.`created_on` > '2020-03-24 00:00:00' AND `AssignedJob`.`created_on` < '2020-03-24 17:18:15');
```

But `data` is just an `[]` empty array.
I also tried using `[Op.between]: [START_DATE, NOW]`, but still I didn't get any record.
I copied the same query to heidsql and ran it, I get the result there.
What's happening here? Can someone explain?

Data type of `created_on` and `updated_on` in sequelize is `DATE`, in the table it's `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the reason why that's happening, I got a fix for it. I have to use `momentjs` to achieve that.

```
const moment = require('moment')
const now = moment()
const  todayAssignedJobs = await AssignedJob.findAll({
         where: {
            created_on: {
                 [Op.gt]: now.startOf('day').toString(),
                 [Op.lt]: now.endOf('day').toString()
              },
            status: 1
           }
     })
```

Same query is still being generated, but it gives result instead of giving an empty array.

```
SELECT `id`, `emp_id`, `zone_id`, `job_id`, `status`, `commission`, `rating`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `created_on`, `updated_on` FROM 
`assigned_jobs` AS `AssignedJob`
WHERE 
(`AssignedJob`.`created_on` > '2020-03-24 00:00:00' AND `AssignedJob`.`created_on` <'2020-03-24 23:59:59') 
AND `AssignedJob`.`status` = 1;
```

If someone got any explanation please comment or feel free to edit this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use moment.js to format the date in `'YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss'`

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const moment = require('moment');
const Op = sequelize.Op

function getDate(withoutTime) {
    const date = new Date();
    if (withoutTime) date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}

const TODAY_START = getDate(true); // '2020-03-24 00:00:00'
const NOW = getDate(); // '2020-03-24 17:47:41'
```

Problem `const TODAY_START = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` will result in Unix time i.e seconds after 1st Jan 1970

```js
const date = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

console.log(date); // return seconds after 1970 

const date1 = new Date();
date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log(date1); // return date
```

Comment: I need records between start of the day and end of the day. `getDateWithoutTime()` will convert both to same date.

Comment: No I didnt' try. If I have to use momentjs, I dont' see any reason to write functions  instead of using that it already has.